# X2go from a windows client to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: windows-7, x2goclient

I set up X2go server with the latest build on the X2go website with Ubuntu 16,04. I am able to get the MacOSX client to login to the Ubuntu16.04 box. Yay! When I try the same with the windows client I get a timeout message saying "Time out connection to xxx.xx.xxx.xx". I tried it on two different computers Windows machines (one running the latest ms-win build x2go build on Windows 10, and another slightly dated version on Windows 7). I tried with different desktop environments - LXDE, XFCE...nothing seems to work.